# How to convert (JDBC) Result Set to Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I am attempting to convert the following resultSet to Hibernate.  Using resultSet gives me 3 values(columns + data).

**JDBC**

```
  String sql = "select name, address, date from info";
    List<String> binding = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(dto.getName() != null){
        sql += " where name=?";
        binding.add(dto.getName());
    }

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    int index=1;
    for(String p: binding){
        log.info("\tindex="+index+", p="+p);
        pstmt.setString((index++), p);
    }
```

**Hibernate**

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("name").addScalar("address").addScalar("date");

  int index=0;
  for(String p: binding){
    log.info("\tindex="+index+", p="+p);
    q.setString((index++), p);
   }

  q.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
  List<Map<String,Object>> resultsToValueMapList=q.list();
```

**ERROR** (When adding 3rd Scaler("date")):

```
 String Errororg.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
```

If i only use the first 2 Scalers I can see results.  I've tried modifying the List arguments but it didn't work.  How do I get all three columns + data to show using result transformer.  Is this the correct way to do this?  I've used AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer in the past to get 2 values but now I need to get 3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify the type:

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
    .addScalar("name", Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("address", Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("date", Hibernate.DATE);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I used your suggestion but used ("name", StringType.INSTANCE) and ("date", DateType.INSTANCE) and it worked.